# Boolean test as argument

Tags: javascript, function, boolean, conditional-statements

I would like to have something looking like this

```
let condition = function(name, cond) {
this.name = name;
this.func = (prop) => {
    if (cond) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

let snow = new condition("temperature", prop < 0);
```

---

I have a temerature value on a separate folder and a function checking if `condition.func` returns true or false. For example it can't snow if temperature is under 0, this means that I would call the `condition.func(temperature)` and this would execute the code `if (temperature < 0){return true}`.
The problem is when I define snow it throws the error that prop is not defined...
I understand this is because I am looking to override a variable not even initialized, but I have no idea of how to implement a boolean test as an argument of a function

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `function` or `arrow-function`with an input parameter to your `condition` and it will be stored in the `cond` prop. And then when you call `func` pass a parameter into the func and use the `cond` reference to call your `cond function` with that given parameter like `cond(prop)`. Also you can simplify your `func` function and refer to only `cond`.

```js
let condition = function(name, cond) {
   this.name = name;
   this.func = cond;
};

let snow = new condition("temperature", prop => prop < 0);

if(snow.func(-2)){
  console.log(`Snowing`);
}
```

Comment: I have never seen an arrow function without () => {}, can you explain what prop => prop < 0 actually is?

Answer (score 1):

You could just hand over the function, without an intermediate function. For the condition, you need a function, like `p => p < 0`, not just a condition, like `prop < 0`. This works only hard coded or with [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), as string, but not as parameter.

```js
function Condition (name, cond) {
    this.name = name
    this.func = cond
}

let snow = new Condition("temperature", p => p < 0);

console.log(snow.func(5));
console.log(snow.func(-5));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a method to check if the value matches your condition. See below for a possible solution.

```js
let condition = function(name, predicate) {
  this.name = name
  // func will take a single value, the temperate to check
  this.func = (prop) => {
      // Execute the predicate method with the provided value.
      return predicate(prop);
  }
}

/**
 * This method will check your condition, it takes a single value as a param
 */
function snowPredicate(value) {
  // It can only snow when value is less than 0.
  return (value < 0);
}

// Set the condition for snow, pass the predicate method as the check.
let snow = new condition("temperature", snowPredicate)

// Check if it can snow when it is 10 degrees and -1 degrees.
console.log(snow.func(10));
console.log(snow.func(-1));
```